# I have an error while using firebase php which is cURL error 35

Tags: php, firebase

I am trying to use **php** with **firebase**

after installing the package "composer require kreait/firebase-php ^4.0"

and adjusting my firebase

it shows me that error:

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 35: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to ff64t.firebaseio.com:443 (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\php_firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:200 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\php_firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(155): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\php_firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(105): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\php_firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(Guz in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\php_firebase\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\ApiException.php on line 40

my php code is so simple:

```
 <?php
 require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
 use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
     use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
 $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/secret/clone-7ef2-642f.json');
 $firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    //->withDatabaseUri("https://ff64t.firebaseio.com")
    ->create();
    $database = $firebase->getDatabase();
    $ref = $database->getReference('users');
    $res = $ref->getChild('1z7ni171Hwgq8fdnandRNjfxBfw2')->getChild('name')->getValue();
    var_dump($res);

?>
```

so anyone has faced something like that and how to solve this problem

I've tried many solutions but none of them works.

I tried to reinstall curl and put it like system variable
I also tried to add

```
curl_setopt($easy->handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

to make curl deal with IPV4... it gave me a new error which is:

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\firebase_php\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:201 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\firebase_php\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(537): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\firebase_php\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(152): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::retryFailedRewind(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #2 C:\xam in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\webservice\firebase_php\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\ApiException.php on line 40

I also checked curl support and ssl from phpinfo

Comment: Hi! It would be great if you could tell us about some of the solutions you've tried already.

Comment: ok, I'm gonna add them in the post

Comment: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.0/troubleshooting.html#curl-error-xx - also, if you‘re on at least PHP 7.2, you should migrate to release 5.x of the SDK 

Comment: I tried the latest SDK version but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have enable curl.cainfo

[image]

You can add cainfo.pem to php.ini (http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `curl(1)` manual page, an error code 35 is an SSL handshake failure:

> ```
> EXIT CODES
>   ...
>   35     SSL connect error. The SSL handshaking failed.
> ```

You can try temporarily disabling the SSL certificate verification to see if that fixes the issue.

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER, 0); // ***JUST A TEST! DO __NOT__ PUSH THIS TO PRODUCTION!***
```

If that does fix the issue, the reason is probably one of the two most common SSL handshake failures:

1. A missing CA certificate on your host machine, meaning that cURL couldn't verify the certificate's authenticity.
2. An expired certificate being presented by the machine you're connecting to.

If that does NOT fix the issue, the reason is probably:

3. Your machine and the remote one couldn't negotiate a cipher suite and/or SSL version.
4. Any number of other SSL errors.

Comment: I tried to execute this good  "composer config -g -- disable-tls true" but the error still existed

Answer (score 0):

On my local, I have only changed DNS to 8.8.8.8 to solve it

Answer (score 0):

While working on my local machine, this is how I got around this, download the **cacert.pem** file from  http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

copy the file to the **php** **location** i.e. if using Wamp

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\cacert.pem

or if using Xampp

> C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem

*****Please note that use the paths in your environment.*

Then if using Wamp edit the **php.ini** file in the apache folder i.e.

> C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin

edit the lines:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\cacert.pem"
```

Or using Xampp

> C:\xampp\php

edit the lines:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem"
```

Then restart your Wamp or Xampp Services, that should do the trick.